# Why do Hindu temples have Bells?

Tags: belief, temple

It is often seen that people who worship gods at temple rung bells when they enter the temple.

These bells are hung generally near the idols or at the entrance of the temples. They are also rung while the devotees are performing *Aarti*.

Even at homes, people have small bells which they ring before they sit for puja *(Act of worship)*

So whats the reason behind ringing those bells?

Comment: Oh God! look I came!

Comment: @hims056 I think its much more than that :D I've heard that ringing those bells hardly helps spreading positive vibrations around and also keeps the demons away

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> It is believed that deities remain manifest in mandirs in which bells
>   (ghanta) are rung. In Hindu mandirs, bells are usually hung in the
>   area or porch preceding the inner sanctum. Devotees ring them as an
>   invocation to the deity to listen to their prãrthnã and be blessed.
>
> There is an art and science of making bells to produce the requisite
>   sounds. There are bells specially made to produce the long strains of
>   the sound OM. The handle of a ghantadi signifies prãna – the vital
>   force in the form of Hanumanji, Garud, Nandi or Chakra. During Garud
>   sthãpanvidhi, the handle is offered pujan. A bell without a handle in
>   one of these forms is forbidden in rituals, since it may augur
>   misfortune. The body of the bell is said to represent the divinity of
>   time (Ãgama-Kosha 1992 VI:99).  (Source:[kids.baps.org](http://kids.baps.org/thingstoknow/hinduism/56.htm)).

[Here](http://www.hinduterminal.org/2013/05/why-do-we-ring-bell-in-temple.html) is a deep scientific analysis of the temple bells.

Bells are also used to inform people to gather for aarti too.

Comment: What does "The body of the bell is said to represent the divinity of time" mean?

Comment: Evens bells have science in them :)

Comment: The link doesn't work. Btw, can you tell the origin of bells in Hindu temples? Was it present during Vedic era?

Comment: I visited kids.baps.org . It doesn't give any reference to any scripture or a sage's writing etc. Just gives the site writer's opinion. So can't be treated as valid script ref. Any Tom, Dick & Harry can create a website and write whatever he/she feels. But that doesn't mean it is always authentic.

Comment: Please consider citing valid source.

Answer (score 5):

For the same reason we chant hymns, sing *Aartis* etc. **They are associated with music.**

[image: a typical bell]

In Hinduism, music is considered a way of worship... In-fact, so much so, it is *associated completely* with worship.

A bell is just another *musical instrument*. It is used for worship because of this reason.

It also creates sounds which create a mythical environment. It can be experienced with day to day life. Go to a temple, hammer a bell, and you will feel more close to the temple, and in a more soothing, sacred world! They create positive vibrations as well.

Answer (score 2):

The Bell which you see here are seen in Siva temples, not in other temples. Thus bells are sounded in Siva temple while entering to awaken rather draw the kid attention of the benevolent God who remains in deep meditation all through. Besides small bells are sounded at the time of offerings of consecrated foods (also incense and lamp) for(a) not to disturb the deity by external noise and (b) for his pleasure. Further a special type of bell is sounded when the deities move in journeys outside the sanctum or the waving of lamps are ceremonially performed. In some prominent temples local resident used to take heir meals only after their revered god is offered with foods. Here cymbals are sounded near the gates of the temples to make others know that now the god is enjoying his food and hence they can either go for food cooked in their houses or can collect Prasad from the temple.

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism.SE!  You should cite sources.