# What is meaning of this Ãgama-Kosha verse for bells?

Tags: temple

> There is an art and science of making bells to produce the requisite
>   sounds. There are bells specially made to produce the long strains of
>   the sound OM. The handle of a ghantadi signifies prãna – the vital
>   force in the form of Hanumanji, Garud, Nandi or Chakra. During Garud
>   sthãpanvidhi, the handle is offered pujan. A bell without a handle in
>   one of these forms is forbidden in rituals, since it may augur
>   misfortune. The body of the bell is said to represent the divinity of
>   time (Ãgama-Kosha 1992 VI:99). (Source:[kids.baps.org](http://kids.baps.org/thingstoknow/hinduism/56.htm)).

Also, reference to it given in [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/711/4166) answer.

What does "The body of the bell is said to ***represent the divinity of time***" mean?

Comment: It could mean that the bell is designed in such a way that all the vibrations stay inside (resonance) the body of the bell (for a long period) akin to all cosmic vibrations happening within the purview of Time